# Filtering data into subplots using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset of three variables: year, age group and result. There are 9 different age groups. What I am trying to do is to create a 3x3 plot where I have 9 subplots with `geom_line()` plots of each subgroups. So far I ended up with a 3x3 plot with all the results in all of the plots which was my step 1. However, I can't seem to find a way to do the last little bit to create my plot. Help is appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

```
# n is a list of unique values aka age groups in the Data1
n <- unique(Data1$age)  

# Preparation for plotting all subplots    
plot_lst <- vector("list", length = length(n))

for (i in 1:length(n)) {
  g <- ggplot(Data1, aes(x=year, y=data, color=age)) +
    geom_line()
  plot_lst[[i]] <- g
}

# Plotting all subplots into one
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = plot_lst, ncol = 3)
```

I know it is currently missing the filtering which I mainly tried to do within the `geom_line()` but I wasn't able to find a working solution.

Found a solution with:

```
ggplot(Data1, aes(year, data)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ age)
```

Comment: Are you aware of the ggplot function `facet_wrap()` - this might do what it sounds like you're after, but if not, clarify why it doesn't do what you want

Comment: I wasn't aware but looking into it I found a 4-line-solution to my problem. Many thanks!!

Comment: @Jezzie FYI you can post an answer to your own question if you think it would be valuable to share with others.